# Opera Browser :hover weirdness

Tags: html, css, opera

I've been developing a site for the past couple of days and have everything working adequately in all major browsers but Opera.  For some unknown reason the navigation won't revert to `display:none;` when I exit the dropdown navigation.

If there's some trick that I'm unaware of please enlighten me.

Problem URL: http://demo.ivannovak.com/iocaste/index.html

Again, everything is fine in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE7+. This problem is specific to Opera.

The relevant HTML:

```
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="page.html">Example Set</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="full-width.html">Full-Width Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="html-test.html">HTML Test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page.html">Normal Page</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="page.html">GrandChild Nav</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="page.html">Normal Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="page.html">Normal Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="page.html">Normal Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Normal Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul><!-- #navigation -->
```

The relevant CSS:

```
#navigation {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:35px;
    z-index:10;
    margin-right:10px;
    list-style: none;
}

#navigation li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#navigation li.active > a,
#navigation li a:hover {
    color:#e5e5e5;
}

#navigation li a {
    color:#b2b2b2;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 12px;
}

#navigation li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:3;
    left:50%;
    margin:0 0 0 -104px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    top:100%;
    list-style: none;
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

#navigation li ul li {
    width:178px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 15px;
    float:none;
}

#navigation > li > ul > li:first-child {
    background:url(../img/child_nav_top.png) no-repeat 50% 0 transparent;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#navigation > li > ul > li {
    background:url(../img/child_nav_repeat.png) repeat-y 50% 0 transparent;
}

#navigation > li > ul > li:last-child {
    background:url(../img/child_nav_bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100% transparent;
    padding-bottom:20px!important;
}

#navigation li.lastChild {


/*  IE 8 is dumb */
    background:url(../img/child_nav_bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100% transparent;
    padding-bottom:20px!important;
}

#navigation li ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none!important;
    z-index:4;
    left:278px;
    top:-15px;
}

#navigation li ul li:hover ul {
    display:block!important;
}

#navigation li ul li ul li {
    float:none;
    width:119px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 8px 0 15px;
}

#navigation > li > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
    background:url(../img/grandChild_nav_top.png) no-repeat 50% 0 transparent;
    padding-top:15px;
}

#navigation > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    background:url(../img/grandChild_nav_repeat.png) repeat-y 50% 0 transparent;
}

#navigation > li > ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
    background:url(../img/grandChild_nav_bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100% transparent;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

#navigation li.lastGrandChild {
    background:url(../img/grandChild_nav_bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100% transparent;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work in Opera 10.53.

Comment: Ah, I was testing in 10.00 beta... probably should have upgraded. *facepalm*

Comment: Opera always has another (dozen) beta(s).

Comment: Also fine in Opera 10.10/Linux.

Comment: Also fine in Opera 10.11/Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was a redraw bug that's been fixed in later releases.